# I can be found near gentle green hills and stony mountains

Tags: riddle, knowledge, wordplay

I can be found near gentle green hills and stony mountains,
Alongside the gas in the clouds and the iron of the earth,
At times I can be white and frosty, red and fiery, or blue and stormy,

What am I?

Hints:

> I seem to have made this riddle too broad, so these hints should help someone solve it:
>
>  1) I've mixed my metaphors everywhere, so "white and frosty" refer to two different things.
>
>  2) Four of the clues are related by the same field of science.
>
>  3) Knowledge tag: There are several clues that I disguised by making the words plural or ending in 'y'.  They are all related to each other in some way, but it requires some specific knowledge.

Comment: well, nice one here! but are we getting too broad here? any hints/ clarifications? thanks

Comment: I think I may have something, solving your previous riddle gave me an idea as to what this could be :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Could you be a

> **giant**?

Note:

> Many of the clues have to do with [Dungeons and Dragons](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giant_(Dungeons_%26_Dragons)), so whenever they appear, I’ll just write “see note.”

I can be found near gentle green hills and stony mountains,

> Gentle = gentle giant (e.g. an elephant)
>  Green = Green Giant (a brand for frozen and canned vegetables)
>  Hill, stone, mountain = see note

Alongside the gas in the clouds and the iron of the earth,

> Gas = gas giant
>  Cloud = see note
>  Iron = *The Iron Giant*
>  Earth = see note

At times I can be white and frosty, red and fiery, or blue and stormy,

> White, red, blue = refer to classifications of [giant stars](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giant_star)
>  Frost, fire, storm = see note

For the hints:

> For hint 2, I believe the common field of science is *astronomy*, due to the multitude of clues that relate to planets. For hint 3, the common association is *Dungeons and Dragons*, as mentioned in the note.

Comment: @JS1 Edited. Nice riddle, enjoyed solving all the clues :)

Answer (score 22):

I say you are

> sonic the hedgehog

I can be found near gentle green hills and stony mountains,

> Green hill is a zone is a lot of sonic games, with stony mountains in the background

Alongside the gas in the clouds and the iron of the earth,

> refer to other zones : Chemical Plant and metropolis

At times I can be white and frosty, red and fiery, or blue and stormy,

> Sonic is mainly blue, and quick like a storm, but he can be white when he become Silver the Hedgehog, and red when you play as Knuckles the Echidna

Comment: Sorry that's not what I was looking for, but it's a very creative answer! +1

Comment: Wow, if this isn’t the answer, I wonder what it actually is...

Answer (score 9):

You are

> a Windows error screen

I can be found near gentle green hills and stony mountains,

> Windows 95 was shipped with a famous background with [green hills](https://www.artsy.net/article/artsy-editorial-story-worlds-famous-desktop-background); mountains pictures are commonly used as desktop background

Alongside the gas in the clouds

> Microsoft, Windows publisher, also provides services on the Cloud

...and the iron of the earth,

> There's a brand new Microsoft project named [Windows Core OS](http://techgenix.com/windows-core-os/)

At times I can be white and frosty

> Windows computers sometimes refuse to start and have a [white screen of death](https://www.google.com/search?q=windows%20white%20screen%20of%20death)

...red and fiery or blue and stormy

> The infamous Windows [blue screen of death](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_screen_of_death) or its less known variant, the [red screen of death](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_screen_of_death#/media/File:Longhorn_RSoD.png)

Comment: Lol, I literally got a rot13(oyhr fperra bs qrngu) while reading this answer.

Comment: It's not the answer I was looking for, but +1 for fitting all the clues.

Answer (score 5):

> the sky

why:

> seen above green hills and mountains,  / seen alongside the clouds /  "the iron of the earth," -> doesn't match / in winter whit and cold, / red and fiery when the sun goes down /or blue and stormy

Comment: rot13(Gur rnegu unf na veba pber (urapr vgf zntargvfz))

Answer (score 4):

You could be

> Oxygen

I can be found near gentle green hills and stony mountains,

> Oxygen can be found everywhere

Alongside the gas in the clouds

> The gas in the cloud is water, or H20, which contains Oxygen

...and the iron of the earth,

> Iron rusts and becomes Ferrous Oxide (FeO) which contains Oxygen

At times I can be white and frosty

> Liquid oxygen is actually bluish (so maybe I'm wrong), but it is very frosty

...red and fiery

> When oxygen fuels a fire, the fire can indeed be red and fiery

...or blue and stormy

> not sure here...  the sky?

So not all fits.  Perhaps the answer is just

> Water, which fits some of the clues also.

Comment: Sorry, that's not it, although some of it fits.  The answer I'm looking for is something completely different, although I knew some parts of the riddle would lead people down the same path you took.

Comment: Rust is composed mainly of _ferric_ oxide (Fe2O3), not ferrous oxide (FeO).

Answer (score 4):

> lime (limestone, lime tree, caustic/weapon lime cloud, impurities with iron-oxides, and in different cocktails/cocktail names)

Comment: Please, please, please, write your answers out line by line. It literally hurts to read this, despite the fact that it's most probably correct.

Comment: No..it was just a quick think, maybe 25%correct..

Comment: Sorry, it's not correct.  Hint: It's not any kind of chemical, element, or compound (since 3 answers so far have guessed as such).

Answer (score 4):

> The answer is a comma.

How?

*I can be found near gentle green hills and stony mountains **,***

> There is a comma near the phrase "gentle green hills and stony mountains".

*Alongside the gas in the clouds and the iron of the earth,*

> alongside "the gas in the clouds and the iron of the earth" there is a comma.

*At times I can be white and frosty, red and fiery, or blue and stormy,*

> this bit might not make sense but "White and frosty", "red and fiery" and "blue or stormy" are just adjectives followed by a comma. I think this line is used the further confuse the audience :)

Answer (score 4):

I think you are:

> **AND**

Taking into account

> your recent addition of [wordplay](/questions/tagged/wordplay), we can see that "and" occurs near every phrase:
>  I can be found *near* gentle green hills **and** stony mountains,
>  *Alongside* the gas in the clouds **and** the iron of the earth,
>  [image: "and" can be formatted as well]

Answer (score 3):

Here's my guess :

> **Water**

---

> Found near the hills and mountains, in clouds, and in the earth's crust( as a component of various compounds, may/may not be ferrous in nature, but found there)

---

> Water can be white and frosty(snow/ice), Blue and stormy(oceans, hurricanes, typhoons etc) and red and fiery... (not sure about this, maybe near volcanos or due to natural pigmentation)

Comment: Sorry, like I said in the comments of the other answer, parts of the riddle seem to fit with this but other parts don't.  But the answer I'm looking for is something completely different.

Answer (score 2):

> The Aurora Borealis a.k.a northern light

It features all the colors mentioned, but what makes me think in this direction is:

> The iron of the earth provides the magnetic field that interacts with ionized gas in the clouds to create the patterns seen in the sky.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to for something that I'm not really convinced is it, but it could fit

> Electricity

I can be found near gentle green hills and stony mountains,

> The gentle green hills of the default windows background image, and stony mountains could be... minecraft?

Alongside the gas in the clouds and the iron of the earth,

> Static electricity forms in clouds, alongside the gases and water droplets. Iron is a very good conductor (iron **of** the earth, not **in** the earth)

At times I can be white and frosty, red and fiery, or blue and stormy,

> A bunch of different forms of electricity, I'm guessing. Blue and stormy is what really tipped me off, as lightning strikes in a storm are often blueish.

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking you are a

> Bluebird

I can be found near gentle green hills and stony mountains,

> Bluebirds can be found in many different parts of the Americas.

Alongside the gas in the clouds and the iron of the earth,

> They can fly and land due to their wings and feet.

At times I can be white and frosty, red and fiery, or blue and stormy,

> Being different colors at different stages of its life:
>  Red and Fiery after hatching - no feathers
>  White and Frosty (more of a grayish) during initial growth stage - first feathers
>  Blue and Stormy as a fully grown adult - adult feathers

Comment: Just adding a much larger explanation as this was my first post and didn't know how things worked. :)

Answer (score 0):

> A corpse

I can be found near gentle green hills and stony mountains,

> Dead bodies are buried

Alongside the gas in the clouds and the iron of the earth,

> Corpses decompose and "return to the elements"

At times I can be white and frosty, red and fiery, or blue and stormy,

> Causes of death can be freezing, burning or killed in a storm.

Comment: Woah, this question gone real dark! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

It's a stretch but maybe points in the right direction

> Damp

I can be found near gentle green hills and stony mountains,

> Damp in sense of mist/haze

Alongside the gas in the clouds

> Clouds form from damp

...and the iron of the earth,

> Damp as a mining terminology (gas mixture within the mine)

At times I can be white and frosty

> Damp/haze in a snowy landscape

...red and fiery

> Damp/haze when the sun rises

...or blue and stormy

> Damp/haze above a stormy see